# Speech Recognition умирает

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-речи, pyaudio

Как можно пофиксить то, что программа выдает ошибку, если не может определить что именно я сказал?

```
    import speech_recognition as sr

query = ''

def record_volume():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone(device_index = 1) as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)

    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'ru-RU')
    print(query)

while query != "1":
    record_volume()
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kompik/Desktop/derm2.py", line 15, in <module>
    record_volume()
  File "C:/Users/Kompik/Desktop/derm2.py", line 11, in record_volume
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'ru-RU')
  File "C:\Users\Kompik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

Не совсем понимаю в чем ошибка.

Comment: Код свой покажите сначала

Comment: Будьте добры приложить код

Comment: Приложил код и текст ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исключение нужно ловить

Попробуйте так:

```
...

while query != "1":
    try:
        record_volume()
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        pass
```

---

**PS.**

В вашем коде `query` никогда не поменяется, хоть в `record_volume` есть `query =` , т.к. это создаст локальную переменную `query`, вместо того, что поменять глобальную. Чтобы менять глобальные переменные в функциях, нужно использовать оператор `global`:

```
def record_volume():
    global query

    ...

    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'ru-RU')
    print(query)
```

А еще лучше не использовать глобальные переменные, а возвращать результат из функции:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def record_volume() -> str:
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone(device_index = 1) as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)

    return r.recognize_google(audio, language='ru-RU')

while True:
    try:
        query = record_volume()
        if query == '1':
            break
    
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Dadassassin, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)